# How do I create text bullets in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

Is there a way to create text bullets in illustrator? I'm trying to mimic or recreate something done in PowerPoint. I think I know how to manually create the character (•), but was hoping there was another way of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Adobe Illustrator contains no feature which generates bulleted lists automatically.

You can set up your own bullets by using a special character at the beginning of each line, then adding a tab, and subsequently adjusting the tabs for the text.

Comment: Yup,.. that's exactly what I've been doing.. curious if there was a simpler way... or is this an oversight from adobe?

Comment: Well Illustrator isn't meant to be used for text-heavy documents. I know it is at times. I don't know I'd call it an "oversight" really.

Comment: I agree that Illustrator is not the tool for that .. indesign probably would be better suited... but with all the character&paragraph properties available in illustrator it seems silly to have left it out.. I still live in hope and happy for someone here to point out that Illustrator is capable of generating bullets

Comment: Illustrator isn't capable of generating bullets. I know for certain. And despite the text engine, there are many, many things missing.

Comment: Its a artificial differentiator, theres no reason why say illustrator and indesign could not be feature identical. But then why make 2 different software? from business perspective it makes sense, not much elsewhere. Product differentiation and all that.

Comment: I agree @joojaa -- There's little reason InDesign and Illustrator could *not* use the same text engine. Unfortunately, they don't.

Comment: It goes deeper than that, theres no reason the pathfinder palette couldnt exist in ps, id, and ae in addition to illustrator for example. In fact theres really nothing stopping indesign and illustrator from a complete merge into one super featured app. Probably tough users could not cope with this.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the alt key and press 0149 on the numeric keyboard (at the bottom right of your keyboard), when you release the alt key, a bullet should appear in your text.Instead of using illustrator you can head for inDesign.

Comment: The person very clearly said they're not looking to manually type bullets

Comment: Thanks Ryan,.. yup,.. I think a few responders are missing the fact that I know how to do this manually or using other programs.. just curious if illustrator itself had this simple option that somehow I missed... thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to generate bullets

Comment: for anyone else who is inclined to attempt this out of curiosity, I think glen meant <shift> + <8> to generate asterisks (*), which are hardly bullets...